# Anti-locking method in VB Scripting?

Tags: vbscript, qtp

If system locks every 5 minutes, what VB Scripting method is used to avoid system locking every 5 minutes?

Comment: Try interact with system using vbs. for example opening start menu.

Comment: Ask your sysadmins why the lock timeout is so short. There may be a reason for it. If not: ask them to increase the timeout to a more reasonable value.

Comment: QTP shouldn't stop working even if the screen is locked. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @PankajJaju, QTP/UFT won't work on locked/logged off machine unless it's running on RDP and you are using UFT version 11.5 or higher.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Save this file in the format of .vbs
Change the Sleep Time *400* based on your requirement.

```
Set wshShell =wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
do
wscript.sleep 400
wshshell.sendkeys "{SCROLLLOCK}"
wscript.sleep 400
loop
```

Comment: Once executed, how do I stop the script?

Comment: @danijel if you go to Task manager you can see wscript.exe , just kill it.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps, WScript.SendKeys could help: 
[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8c6yea83%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Something like double-ScrollLock, I guess?

PS. You'll need to put that in a loop with a sleep, of course.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and easiest way is to open windows media player and run the supplied Wildlife in HD video in repeat mode and then minimize it.
Problem solved, it won't allow the system to get lock automatically. No need for VBS.

Another option is to use small utility called **[Caffeine](http://www.zhornsoftware.co.uk/caffeine/)**. Just download, extract and double click the .exe to run. It will run in background and will do the trick for you.