# How to keep the system awake by sending Keypresses using VBS script?

Tags: windows, vbscript, mouseevent, simulation, keyboard-events

I have a device which has really low standby timeout(2Mins).
So I wanted to build a VBS script that will launch notepad and send Keystrokes so that the system can be kept awake.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Anti-locking method in VB Scripting?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32519036)

Comment: https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2020/05/keepdisplayon-runs-program-preventing.html is the inbuilt way of not sleeping.

Comment: In built way of what? That is just a port to VB.Net.

Comment: The correct way for a program to stay awake.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadexecutionstate and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/power/system-sleep-criteria

Answer (score 1):

After scratching my head on online forums, I have come up with a code to write **Hi** repeatedly. I hope it will benefit the community.

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "notepad"
WScript.Sleep 100
Dim x
x = 1
set service = GetObject ("winmgmts:")
Function IsAppRunning(AppName)
    for Each Process in Service.Instancesof("Win32_Process")
        If UCase(Process.Name) = UCase(AppName) then
            IsAppRunning = True
            Exit function
        End If
    next
    IsAppRunning = False
End Function

While x < 1000 


AppName = "notepad.exe"

If IsAppRunning(AppName) then
WshShell.AppActivate "Notepad"
WshShell.SendKeys "H"
WScript.Sleep 5000
else
    Wscript.quit
End If

If IsAppRunning(AppName) then
WshShell.AppActivate "Notepad"
WshShell.SendKeys "i" 
WScript.Sleep 5000
else
    Wscript.quit
End If

x=x+1
Wend
```

To stop the script from execution just exit the notepad. The code can be modified to run for greater/smaller duration by changing while loop count. Currently the script runs for close to 3 hours or until user closes the notepad. Sorry, that I am not asking any question here but just providing what I made.

Comment: Personally, the script would work better enclosed in a function that allows passing in the delay values as arguments, maybe even passed in from the command line if needed. However, as the past duplicates show there are simpler ways of approaching this.